# jQuery UI modal dialog form using remote content

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui, web-applications

I have a form in a web page dynamically generated and I would like to display it using a the jQuery UI modal dialog.

How can I display the modal dialog form with the remote existing form (myform.html) as content when I click on a link "Open Form"?
Clicking on submit button should close the dialog form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will load the content of `myform.html` into the element with ID `formContainer`, make the `formContainer` a modal dialog (showing the form). When submitting the form, the dialog will be closed

```
$("#formContainer").load("myform.html", function() {
    var container = $(this);
    container.dialog({
        modal: true
    })
    .find("form").submit(function() {
        container.dialog("close");
        return false;
    });
});
```