# jQuery modal dialog using loading a form page that already contain jQuery code (Autocomplete) content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a form in a web page dynamically generated and I would like to display it using a the jQuery UI modal dialog.

The solution I was proposed in a previous post works when my form does not embedded jQuery UI itself : [jQuery UI modal dialog form using remote content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338586/jquery-ui-modal-dialog-form-using-remote-content).

The way the remote form already contains jQuery functions : Autocomplete.

How to solve that problem?

```
<body>
    <div>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>software </th>
                    <th>script</th>
                    <th>exec_type</th>
                    <th>run_status</th>
                    <th>test_result</th>
                    <th>review_status</th>
                    <th>priority</th>
                    <th>author</th>
                    <th>creation date</th>
                    <th>update date</th>
                    <th>edit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>software </th>
                    <th>script</th>
                    <th>exec_type</th>
                    <th>run_status</th>
                    <th>test_result</th>
                    <th>review_status</th>
                    <th>priority</th>
                    <th>author</th>
                    <th>creation date</th>
                    <th>update date</th>
                    <th>edit</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>

            <tbody>

            </tbody>



        </table>

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        $('td').click( function(){$("#formContainer").load("myform.html", function() {
                var container = $(this);
                container.dialog({
                    modal: true
                })
                .find("form").submit(function() {
                    container.dialog("close");
                    return false;
                });
            });

        })
        ;
    </script>



</body>
```

**form.html looks like that:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        (function($) {
            $.widget("ui.combobox", {
                _create: function() {
                    var self = this;
                    var select = this.element.hide();
                    var input = $("<input>")
                    .insertAfter(select)
                    .autocomplete({
                        source: function(request, response) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp(request.term, "i");
                            response(select.children("option").map(function() {
                                var text = $(this).text();
                                if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                                    return {
                                        id: this.value,
                                        label: text.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                                        value: text
                                    };
                            }));
                        },
                        delay: 0,
                        change: function(event, ui) {
                            if (!ui.item) {
                                // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                $(this).val("");
                                return false;
                            }
                            select.val(ui.item.id);
                            self._trigger("selected", event, {
                                item: select.find("[value='" + ui.item.id + "']")
                            });

                        },
                        minLength: 0
                    })
                    .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

                    // This line added to set default value of the combobox
                    input.val(jQuery("#"+select.attr("id")+" :selected").text() )

                    $("<button>&nbsp;</button>")
                    .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                    .attr("title", "Show All Items")
                    .insertAfter(input)
                    .button({
                        icons: {
                            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                        },
                        text: false
                    }).removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                    .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon")
                    .click(function() {
                        // close if already visible
                        if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                            input.autocomplete("close");
                            return false;
                        }
                        // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                        input.autocomplete("search", "");
                        input.focus();
                        return false
                    });
                }
            });

    })(jQuery);

    $(function() {
            $("#id_software").combobox();
            $("#id_script").combobox();

    });



</script>


<body>
    <div>
        <form action="/followup/forms/runs/8/" method="post">
            <p><label for="id_software">Software:</label> <select name="software" id="id_software">

                    <option value="">---------</option>
                    <option value="1" selected="selected">AS_1500_211</option>
                    <option value="2">AS_1500_212</option>
                    <option value="3">AS_1500_213</option>
                    <option value="4">AS_1500_214</option>
                </select></p>
            <p><label for="id_script">Script:</label> <select name="script" id="id_script">
                    <option value="">---------</option>
                    <option value="1">OBJECT__1_TC1</option>

                    <option value="2">OBJECT__2_TC1</option>
                    <option value="3">OBJECT__2_TC2</option>
                    <option value="4">OBJECT__3_TC1</option>
                    <option value="5">OBJECT__3_TC2</option>
                    <option value="6">OBJECT__4_TC1</option>
                    <option value="7">OBJECT__4_TC2</option>
                </select></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you explain the question better?

What is your html? How are you loading the form in?

Comment: My problem was that I had the body tags nested in the parent html. It woks better but it still look very bad after merging the tags and their content

Answer (score 1):

so I know that this is an old post, but i don't see an answer here.  I believe what you need is something like a jquery plugin called livequery.  It will allow you to add the jquery-ui features to your table that gets loaded dynamically by waiting until they exist in the dom.

current:

```
$(function() {
        $("#id_software").combobox();
        $("#id_script").combobox();
});
```

with livequery:

```
$(function() {
        $("#id_software").livequery(function() { $(this).combobox(); });
        $("#id_script").livequery(function() { $(this).combobox(); });
});
```