# Trying to open js or jquery window to include php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to find a way to open my script forgot_success.php in a window or jquery modal. I can code the jquery/JS, but i cannot get the code to fire without error. Can someone show me how to open code in a window from my code. Many thanks

```
$forgotpass_transaction->registerTrigger("END", "Trigger_Default_Redirect", 99, "forgot_success.php");
```

Comment: It's not clear what your supplied code is doing nor how it relates to your question.

Comment: I thought it was clear. the script forgot_success.php needs to open in a new window. At the moment it opens in the parent. The code is called once a user makes a request for a new password. The code itself is irrelavant just how to have the script open in a new window. How do I open that file in a new window rather than parent. Thanks

Comment: If it's irrelevant then why show it? I really don't understand. You're asking me to fix your code but you're only showing me irrelevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poorly worded question but this is almost certainly the answer you are looking for:

[jQuery UI modal dialog form using remote content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338586/jquery-ui-modal-dialog-form-using-remote-content)

Just replace "myform.html" with "forgot_success.php"

Comment: How do i call that from my code as i have no click to function. thanks

Comment: You haven't shown your code. That bit you showed is just a method call, it provides zero context, which is why I said your question is poorly worded. You may as well ask me how you get to work in the morning, I have no idea unless you tell me where you live and where you work first. The link I provided shows you all the code you need, so I don't understand your question. Just paste it in, it calls itself. If you want it to click, then put it in a click event.